# Why does surfaceDimensions (appear) to return a doubly enclosed vector (V2 V2 CInt)?

Tags: haskell, sdl

The following code fails to type check:

```
surfDim :: SDL.V2 CInt
surfDim = SDL.surfaceDimensions surfIn
```

The full error:

```
    * Couldn't match type `SDL.V2 CInt' with `CInt'
      Expected type: SDL.V2 CInt
        Actual type: SDL.V2 (SDL.V2 CInt)
    * In the expression: SDL.surfaceDimensions surfIn
      In an equation for `surfDim':
          surfDim = SDL.surfaceDimensions surfIn
      In an equation for `scaleSurface':
          scaleSurface surfIn box scale
            = do surfOut <- createScreenSurface sizeCIntScaled
                 _ <- SDL.surfaceBlitScaled
                        surfIn
                        (Just (fmap fromIntegral boxFinal))
                        surfOut
                        (Just boxFinalScaled)
                 return surfOut
            where
                boxFinal
                  = case box of
                      Just b -> b
                      Nothing
                        -> SDL.Rectangle
                             origin (fmap (fmap fromIntegral) (SDL.surfaceDimensions surfIn))
                boxFinalScaled
                  = fmap (fromIntegral . (* (fromIntegral scale))) boxFinal
                sizeCIntScaled = boxSize boxFinalScaled
                origin :: SDL.Point SDL.V2 Int
                ....
    |
232 |     surfDim = SDL.surfaceDimensions surfIn
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm still confused after looking at [the code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sdl2-2.4.1.0/docs/src/SDL.Video.Renderer.html#surfaceDimensions) for `surfaceDimensions`:

```
surfaceDimensions :: MonadIO m => Surface -> m (V2 CInt)
surfaceDimensions (Surface s _) = liftIO $ (V2 <$> Raw.surfaceW <*> Raw.surfaceH) <$> peek s
```

Since `V2` (rightly to me) [doesn't seem to have an instance of MonadIO](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sdl2-2.4.1.0/docs/SDL-Vect.html#t:V2), I don't know why this is happening, but my best guess is that it is satisfying it and I don't know why or how (probably due to my incomplete understanding of [liftIO](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't.  You are running afoul of the tendency of the type checker to unify as far as it can before reporting an error message.  In this case, the type checker thinks, "Oh, this expression has type `m something`, and I want a `V2 something`.  So `m` must be `V2`."  It defers until later checking that `m = V2` satisfies that `MonadIO` constraint.  And before it gets there, it looks inside the top-level type, and realizes that it can't unify `V2 CInt` with `CInt`, so it fails before ever checking whether `V2` is a monad.

As a human, you might respond to being wrong by backing up and questioning which of your assumptions was wrong.  The type checker doesn't do that at all.  Instead, it assumes that all of its assumptions were fine up until the point that it was impossible to proceed.  Then it complains about the very last step.  It's fairly common that it's gone down some bizarre rabbit hole by then, which is why Haskell type errors are kind of notoriously bad, especially when there are type classes involved as there are here.

Now, here's the actual mistake.  You need to compute the dimensions in the `IO` monad (or some other instance of `MonadIO`).  Which means you need to do:

```
surfDim <- SDL.surfaceDimensions surfIn
```

in some appropriate `do` block.  You can't make it just an ordinary equation.

Comment: The funny thing is, I knew I likely had the type wrong due to the lack of MonadIO (or any monad embedding the result), but I guess I had grown too reliant on the type checker to tell me what my type should be in this particular case. I'll try to keep unification in mind in the future.

Comment: @bbarker, unfortunately, it's not that easy for the type checker to figure out which of the contradictory things you told it was wrong. Arranging to be able to backtrack to investigate a type error seems *very* expensive. It would be interesting to see if there's some way to display a certain amount of the type checker history (as in `-ddump-tc-trace`) in a normal-human-readable format. It sounds difficult.

Comment: As errors go, I think I've seen a lot worse in other (non mainstream) languages, and can imagine myself getting used to this situation without too much trouble.

Comment: @bbarker: When you encounter a type error, it helps a lot to add type annotations here and there to help narrow down where your expectations and the compiler’s inferences differ. And over time you’ll develop an intuition of “when I see this error, I probably made this sort of mistake” anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here - getting your code to compile, and getting better error messages from GHC.  If you post more of your code, we can help more with the first.

Do you get a more useful error if you leave off the type signature for `surfDim`?

Neither `V2 CInt` nor `V2 (V2 CInt)` are possible types.  You need something like `IO (V2 CInt)`, to satisfy `MonadIO m`.

GHC tried to pick a type for `m`, guided by the `V2 CInt` type sig, and decided that `m ~ V2`.  Unfortunately, this choice didn't lead to a helpful error message.  If you use the type sig in suggests as "Actual type", I believe GHC will get far enough into the typechecking process to notice that there is no instance `MonadIO V2`, as you point out.

I have no idea if it's possible to get GHC to consistently give better advice about this sort of thing.  When I'm stumped by a type error, I like to try both adding more type sigs or taking some out.  There are often different error messages, and one may make more sense to me than the other.